# Trigrams comparison

Tags: c#, n-gram

I am fairly new to coding so I guess I´m not seeing the obvious answer by myself so I am sorry if this is a silly question but I´m really stucked here. I am trying to compare two sets of trigrams from two different texts (A and B). If there are no trigrams in B present on A, then I would say those two texts are different, at least for my present purpose. I am using [Nuve](https://github.com/hrzafer/nuve) for trigram extraction.

So far I have this:

```
        var paragraph = "This is not a phrase. This is not a sentence.";
        var paragraph2 = "This is a phrase. This is a sentence. This have nothing to do with sentences.";
        ITokenizer tokenizer = new ClassicTokenizer(true);
        SentenceSegmenter segmenter = new TokenBasedSentenceSegmenter(tokenizer);
        var sentences = segmenter.GetSentences(paragraph);
        ITokenizer tokenizer2 = new ClassicTokenizer(true);
        SentenceSegmenter segmenter2 = new TokenBasedSentenceSegmenter(tokenizer2);
        var sentences2 = segmenter2.GetSentences(paragraph2);


        var extractor = new NGramExtractor(3);
        var grams1 = extractor.ExtractAsList(sentences);
        var grams2 = extractor.ExtractAsList(sentences2);

        var nonintersect = grams2.Except(grams1);


        foreach (var nGram in nonintersect)
        {
            var current = nGram;
            bool found = false;
            foreach (var n in grams2)
            {

                if (!found)
                {
                    if (n == current)
                    {
                        found = true;

                    }
                }
            }
            if (!found)
            {
                var result = current;
                string finalresult = Convert.ToString(result);
                textBox3.AppendText(finalresult+ "\n");

            }
```

This way I hope to get the sentences that, being in B, are not present in A (i.e. all the sentences from B in the example), but now I would have to compare each trigram from B to each trigram from A to see if sentences are really different from each other. I have tried to do so with another nested foreach but I get just nonsense data, as follows:

```
 foreach (var sentence2 in sentences2)
        {
            var actual = sentence2;
            bool found1 = false;

            foreach (var sentence in sentences)
            {

                if (!found1) 
                {
                   if (actual == sentence)
                   {
                   found1 = true;
                   }
                }

            }

            if (!found1)
            {

                    string finalresult= Convert.ToString(actual);
                    textBox3.AppendText(finalresult+ "\n");

            }

        }
```

Doing this I try to verify if the trigrams from each sentence in B are equal to the trigrams from each sentence in A and, if they are, then textBox3 would be empty.

Briefly, I am trying to code something similar to [Ferret](https://github.com/petercrlane/ferret) but for C# and only for comparing two given plain texts. As far as I know, there is nothing similar already done for C#.

Any help or tip would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: At first glance, `found = !found` looks suspicious - it's an assignment that flips `found`. Changing that to `found == !found` still doesn't make sense, because that always evaluates to `false`. You likely meant to use `if (!found)` - 'if found is not true, then...'.

Comment: Also note that `List<T>` has a `Contains` method. Alternately, you could use Linq's `Any` method, which works with everything that's enumerable - lists, arrays, sets, and so on. If you must use a loop, remember that you can break out of it as soon as you find a match with the `break` keyword, which eliminates the need to check `found` within the loop.

Comment: Ok, thank you Pieter. Let´s suppose we are using `if(!found)` then.

Comment: You may also want to add proper type information to the code in your post - `var` is convenient, but when posting small pieces of code it does hide useful information.

Comment: Sure, you are right on there. Regarding Linq, I guess that would be an alternative option, I don´t really know if it would make any difference.

Comment: Feel free to edit your post to update the code. You may also want to clarify what results you expect for the given data (and what results you actually get).

Comment: Sure! Done, thank you!

Comment: So to clarify: you want to check for similarities between two pieces of text by comparing sentence-level trigrams. Are you looking for a boolean result (`bool AreTextsSimilar(string a, string b)`) or do you also want to know which sentences they have in common (`IEnumerable<string> GetSharedSentences(string a, string b)`)? Do you want all shared sentences or only shared sentences that are part of shared sentence trigrams?

Comment: As for your code, the first loop will never give any result, because `nonintersect` is a subset of `grams2`, so for every trigram in `nonintersect` you'll always find a match in `grams2`, and you only show something when there's no match. The second loop shows all sentences that are unique to `paragraph2`. If you change the `if` statement to `if (found1)` it would show all sentences that are found in both paragraphs. All in all, the code doesn't really show what you actually want to achieve, hence my questions for clarifications.

Comment: Answering your questions, 1) yes, I´m only looking for a boolean result and 2) I want to extract the sentences in B that do not share trigrams with sentences in A.

Comment: I assume 2) means: get all sentences in B that are not part of sentence trigrams that occur in both A and B? So if A is `"A. B. C. D."` and B is `"A. B. C. D. E. F."`, the shared trigrams are `"A. B. C."` and `"B. C. D."` (which means that A and B are similar), so you want sentences `"E."` and `"F."` to be returned, right? So you do want two methods after all? Or are you looking for sentences that do not share word-level trigrams?

Comment: The last one is right: I´m looking for sentences that do not share word-level trigrams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comparing bodies of text**

Comparing two bodies of text and marking them as similar if they have at least one sentence-level trigram in common is fairly straight-forward:

```
public bool AreTextsSimilar(string a, string b)
{
    // We can reuse these objects - they could be stored in member fields:
    ITokenizer tokenizer = new ClassicTokenizer(true);
    SentenceSegmenter segmenter = new TokenBasedSentenceSegmenter(tokenizer);
    NGramExtractor trigramExtractor = new NGramExtractor(3);

    IEnumerable<string> sentencesA = segmenter.GetSentences(a);
    IEnumerable<string> sentencesB = segmenter.GetSentences(b);

    // The order of trigrams doesn't matter, so we'll fetch them as sets instead,
    // to make comparisons between their elements more efficient:
    ISet<NGram> trigramsA = trigramExtractor.ExtractAsSet(sentencesA);
    ISet<NGram> trigramsB = trigramExtractor.ExtractAsSet(sentencesB);

    // 'Intersect' returns all elements that are found in both collections:
    IEnumerable<NGram> sharedTrigrams = trigramsA.Intersect(trigramsB);

    // 'Any' only returns true if the collection isn't empty:
    return sharedTrigrams.Any();
}
```

Without `Linq` methods (`Intersect`, `Any`), those last two lines could be implemented as a loop:

```
    foreach (NGram trigramA in trigramsA)
    {
        // As soon as we find a shared sentence trigram we can conclude that
        // the two bodies of text are indeed similar:
        if (trigramsB.Contains(trigramA))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Sentences without shared word trigrams**

Retrieving all sentences that do not share word-level trigrams takes some more work:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetUniqueBSentences(string a, string b)
{
    // We can reuse these objects - they could be stored in member fields:
    ITokenizer tokenizer = new ClassicTokenizer(true);
    SentenceSegmenter segmenter = new TokenBasedSentenceSegmenter(tokenizer);
    NGramExtractor trigramExtractor = new NGramExtractor(3);

    IEnumerable<string> sentencesA = segmenter.GetSentences(a);
    IEnumerable<string> sentencesB = segmenter.GetSentences(b);

    ITokenizer wordTokenizer = new ClassicTokenizer(false);
    foreach (string sentenceB in sentencesB)
    {
        IList<string> wordsB = wordTokenizer.Tokenize(sentenceB);
        ISet<NGram> wordTrigramsB = trigramExtractor.ExtractAsSet(wordsB);

        bool foundMatchingSentence = false;
        foreach (string sentenceA in sentencesA)
        {
            // This will be repeated for every sentence in B. It would be more efficient
            // to generate trigrams for all sentences in A once, before we enter these loops:
            IList<string> wordsA = wordTokenizer.Tokenize(sentenceA);
            ISet<NGram> wordTrigramsA = trigramExtractor.ExtractAsSet(wordsA);

            if (wordTrigramsA.Intersect(wordTrigramsB).Any())
            {
                // We found a sentence in A that shares word-trigrams, so stop comparing:
                foundMatchingSentence = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // No matching sentence in A? Then this sentence is unique to B:
        if (!foundMatchingSentence)
            yield return sentenceB;
    }
}
```

Apparently `segmenter` also returns an extra, empty sentence, which you may want to filter out (or figure out how to prevent `segmenter` from doing that).

I'm sure the above code can be optimized if performance is a concern, but I'll leave that up to you.